Is interpreting information conservation as time reversibility non-mainstream physics?
I understand the following as standard results in modern physics.

Black holes evaporate over time via Hawking radiation.
Small black holes evaporate over very short times.
There is an "information paradox" pertaining uniquely to black holes which says it is impossible to reverse the process of information bearing matter falling into black holes. and eventually getting converted into hawking radiation.
There is a process called annihilation where matter and anti-matter annihilate with each other and create photons. The information paradox doesn't apply to this process.

I am, however, confused by some implications of these assumptions. Firstly, it seems to be that the information paradox would apply not just to matter falling into a large black hole, but also to the matter itself getting compressed into a small black hole and evaporating near-instantaneously (due to the small mass of the matter). However, I do not understand why the information paradox would not be a problem in the similar process of matter-antimatter annihilation. What makes black hole evaporation unique in this sense?

Questions about why a specific question got closed should be asked on Meta. Due to this, this new question may be closed as well. You may want to rephrase it so as to make the new question clearly about physics, not the dynamics of the website. This also involves understanding why the first question got closed. Finally, when a question gets closed you should not open a new one asking the same thing, but rather edit the closed one

I do not understand why the original question was closed, though. There was a clear backslash that may be due to your (very minor) use of Chat GPT in the original post, but it seems a perfectly acceptable and reasonable question to me. I'll vote to reopen it

Sure. I figured understanding which of the things I said were non-mainstream was a physics question, which is why I asked it here.

It is a question about a physics question, not a question about physics. This is well-suited to the Physics Meta but not to the main Physics page.

I was going to delete this and ask on meta, but there is already an answer now. So, I'll leave it and let them close it. I did ask a similar question on mathexchange (about another question) in the past and it seemed to be fine back then.

@RohitPandey Please edit this question to make it a pure physics question. Since there are already two questions about the same topic (this one and the original one), either of them can be closed as a duplicate later.

Sure, edited the question to focus more on the Physics aspects.

This whole topic about BH "information paradox" is really a weird obsession of some theorists and science communicators, it is not some important question in physics, which is why, I think, questions on it attract downvotes; there is too much black hole paradox talk in the air already, and it's importance is grossly exaggerated. Some people don't like the irreversibility in black holes or QT, and try to think of ways to recover reversibility there. This is fine as an obscure logical/mathematical problem, but the public interest and marketing around it is completely off base.

I understand. Sabine Hossenfelder has made multiple videos expressing similar opinions on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHR-ggwafO8. This will sound like hyperbole, but I do think we will someday run simulations of the universe and the answers to such questions might be important then to make sure we do them accurately?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics but about an opinion of what is mainstream physics.

@ZeroTheHero.- there are follow up questions about physics once there is confirmation on the key premises being mainstream. The reason I was forced to do this is because the previous one was closed due to not being mainstream.

@NíckolasAlves the questions cannot be answered using physics as the premise is to spark a debate in the definition of mainstream physics.  Like “am I a crank and if not …”. What is the question here: is it about mainstream physics or the follow up?

There is absolutely nothing wrong with a question framed as: "are these premised valid and if so, I have a follow-up question". I think you're talking some liberties in alleging that I'm intending to spark a debate.

@RohitPandey I actually agree with ZeroTheHero on this. I think your question is pertinent as long as it is phrased along the lines of "Why doesn't the information paradox apply to particle annihilation?", but asking whether something is or not mainstream is not adequate for this site. More specifically, the follow-up questions are valid questions in this site, but the rest of the post is not.

@ZeroTheHero When I answered the question, I read it as "Why doesn't the information paradox apply to particle annihilation?", which seemed to be OP's main point. I had the same impression of the previous post quoted by OP. I agree the current version of this post is off-topic

@RohitPandey I edited the question to fit it into the site's guidelines. Please check if the new version corresponds to your original intent with the question

Yes, this new version looks good.

@RohitPandey ANNIHILATION: You come to a bank with a cash in a pocket. The bank takes your cash and sends it out as an investment. The serial numbers on your bills (the “information”) remain intact. EVAPORATION: You approach a bank with a cash in a pocket. They see you coming and start sending cash out before you come in. You haven’t given them any bills yet, but the amount of cash in your pocket reduces. When you enter the bank, you have no cash left, the bank already has sent all the cash out without taking any bills from you. The serial numbers from your bills (the “information”) disappear.


Is interpreting information conservation as time reversibility non-mainstream physics?

This is actually the mainstream interpretation. The "paradox" in the black hole information paradox is exactly that the evolution of a black hole is not time-reversible in the sense that given only information about what happens after the black hole evaporated, it would be impossible to compute the initial state before the evaporation. In the jargon, we say the evolution is not unitary. The dynamics is not time-reversible in the sense that given the past you can predict the future, but given the future you cannot "postdict" the past. You can't run the evolution backwards and compute what happened in the past.
This is very different from the annihilation example. If we annihilate an object of matter and one of antimatter, then the resulting radiation will still have all of the original information. In other words, if you had complete knowledge about the radiation, you would be able to compute everything there was to know about the original matter-antimatter system. If you threw them into a black hole, then the Hawking radiation would not contain everything you'd need to reconstruct the original setup. In this sense, information is lost.
I am answering your question based on the predictions of Hawking's original calculation about black hole evaporation, and I'm trusting the calculation to the very end. Notice, however, that this is an active area of research and there is no established consensus on this topic.

Meta comment: while I think the question as it stands needs some editing, I think it is already possible to see what exactly OP would like to know, and the edits are fairly simple (although a bit extensive). I guesses it would do no harm to answer the question already, and maybe close the old question as a duplicate to this one later

The information paradox is more than what you explain it to be. Take a test particle falling to a black hole. The coordinate time of the particle reaching the horizon is infinite. The coordinate time of the full evaporation is finite. Therefore the black hole evaporates before the particle hits the horizon. The paradox is that the mass/energy of the particle evaporates with the black hole, but all other quantum numbers (the “information”) do not, because the particle never reaches the horizon and must remain intact. The particle cannot keep existing without its energy, so it is assumed gone.

Hence all its quantum numbers (the “information”) are assumed gone for an unknown reason. This applies to every particle and so to the entire mass of the collapsing star. Nothing ever reaches or crosses the apparent horizon, everything disappears from existence before the event horizon is formed. The proposed resolution is that the horizon is a physical singularity called a “firewall” where geodesics of all particles end. Thus the quantum theory proves the original view of Schwarzschild as correct that the horizon is located at spacelike $r=0$ (evident from the metric) and is “the mass point”.

Your explanation also applies to a non-evaporating black hole, because we cannot recreate the past backward from the singularity. However, there is no paradox in this case, so the explanation is not exactly solid. The actual paradox is not in the fact that the information is lost. It is lost in the Schwarzschild black hole too, but without a paradox.  The actual paradox is that two different observers expect two mutually exclusive outcomes in the same situation. You see the black hole vanish into the radiation, but the collapsing matter never reaches the horizon and expects to remain intact.

The mass of a black hole consists of the mass/energy of the fallen matter, which remains outside the horizon and thus is not quite a part of the black hole. When a black hole evaporates, all mass/energy of this matter disappears. So the paradox is that what actually evaporates is the matter outside the black hole. This is impossible, so either there is no evaporation or else this matter is not outside, but actually hits the firewall. Thus either QFT or GR fails at the horizon.
